# How can I mod formmail so that the error page still sends and email and redirects?

Tags: php, perl, forms, formmail

So far it submits the email but no matter what I do it will not redirect (server errors) and I need to redirect it to a custom error page.

How would I modify this to make it work?

Original code:

```
# If any error fields have been found, send error message to the user.   #
    if (@error) { &error('missing_fields', @error) }
```

new code:

```
    if (@error) { # Print HTTP header and opening HTML tags.                           #
        print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
        print "<html>\n <head>\n";

        # Print out title of page                                            #
        if ($Config{'title'}) { print "<title>$safeConfig{'title'}</title>\n" }
        else                  { print "<title>Thank You</title>\n"        }

        print " </head>\n <body";

        # Get Body Tag Attributes                                            #
        &body_attributes;

        # Close Body Tag                                                     #
        print ">\n  <center>\n";

        # Print custom or generic title.                                     #
        if ($Config{'title'}) { print "<h1>$safeConfig{'title'}</h1>\n" }
        else { print "<h1>Thank You For Filling Out This Form</h1>\n" }

        print "</center>\n";

        print "Below is what you submitted to $safeConfig{'recipient'} on ";
        print "$date<p><hr size=1 width=75\%><p>\n";

        # If a sort order is specified, sort the form fields based on that.  #
        if ($Config{'sort'} =~ /^order:.*,.*/) {

            # Set the temporary $sort_order variable to the sorting order,   #
            # remove extraneous line breaks and spaces, remove the order:    #
            # directive and split the sort fields into an array.             #
            $sort_order = $Config{'sort'};
            $sort_order =~ s/(\s+|\n)?,(\s+|\n)?/,/g;
            $sort_order =~ s/(\s+)?\n+(\s+)?//g;
            $sort_order =~ s/order://;
            @sorted_fields = split(/,/, $sort_order);

            # For each sorted field, if it has a value or the print blank    #
            # fields option is turned on print the form field and value.     #
            foreach $sorted_field (@sorted_fields) {
                local $sfname = &clean_html($sorted_field);

                if ($Config{'print_blank_fields'} || $Form{$sorted_field} ne '') {
                    print "<b>$sfname:</b> $Form{$sorted_field}<p>\n";
                }
            }
        }

        # Otherwise, use the order the fields were sent, or alphabetic.      #
        else {

            # Sort alphabetically if requested.
            if ($Config{'sort'} eq 'alphabetic') {
                @Field_Order = sort @Field_Order;
            }

            # For each form field, if it has a value or the print blank      #
            # fields option is turned on print the form field and value.     #
            foreach $field (@Field_Order) {
                local $fname = &clean_html($field);

                if ($Config{'print_blank_fields'} || $Form{$field} ne '') {
                    print "<b>$fname:</b> $Form{$field}<p>\n";
                }
            }
        }

        print "<p><hr size=1 width=75%><p>\n";

        # Check for a Return Link and print one if found.                    #
        if ($Config{'return_link_url'} && $Config{'return_link_title'}) {
            print "<ul>\n";
            print "<li><a href=\"$safeConfig{'return_link_url'}\">$safeConfig{'return_link_title'}</a>\n";
            print "</ul>\n";
        }

        # Print the page footer.                                             #
        print <<"(END HTML FOOTER)";
        <hr size=1 width=75%><p> 
        <center><font size=-1><a href="http://www.scriptarchive.com/formmail.html">FormMail</a> V1.92 &copy; 1995 - 2002  Matt Wright<br>
A Free Product of <a href="http://www.scriptarchive.com/">Matt's Script Archive, Inc.</a></font></center>
        </body>
       </html>
(END HTML FOOTER)
    }
}
sub send_mail {
    # Localize variables used in this subroutine.                            #
    local($print_config,$key,$sort_order,$sorted_field,$env_report);

    # Open The Mail Program
    open(MAIL,"|$mailprog 1>&2");

    print MAIL "To: $Config{'recipient'}\n";
    print MAIL "From: $Config{'email'} ($Config{'realname'})\n";

    # Check for Message Subject
    if ($Config{'subject'}) { print MAIL "Subject: $Config{'subject'}\n\n" }
    else                    { print MAIL "Subject: WWW Form Submission\n\n" }

    print MAIL "Below is the result of your feedback form.  It was submitted by\n";
    print MAIL "$Config{'realname'} ($Config{'email'}) on $date\n";
    print MAIL "-" x 75 . "\n\n";

    if (@Print_Config) {
        foreach $print_config (@Print_Config) {
            if ($Config{$print_config}) {
                print MAIL "$print_config: $Config{$print_config}\n\n";
            }
        }
    }

    # If a sort order is specified, sort the form fields based on that.      #
    if ($Config{'sort'} =~ /^order:.*,.*/) {

        # Remove extraneous line breaks and spaces, remove the order:        #
        # directive and split the sort fields into an array.                 #
        local $sort_order = $Config{'sort'};
        $sort_order =~ s/(\s+|\n)?,(\s+|\n)?/,/g;
        $sort_order =~ s/(\s+)?\n+(\s+)?//g;
        $sort_order =~ s/order://;
        @sorted_fields = split(/,/, $sort_order);

        # For each sorted field, if it has a value or the print blank        #
        # fields option is turned on print the form field and value.         #
        foreach $sorted_field (@sorted_fields) {
            if ($Config{'print_blank_fields'} || $Form{$sorted_field} ne '') {
                print MAIL "$sorted_field: $Form{$sorted_field}\n\n";
            }
        }
    }

    # Otherwise, print fields in order they were sent or alphabetically.     #
    else {

        # Sort alphabetically if specified:                                  #
        if ($Config{'sort'} eq 'alphabetic') {
            @Field_Order = sort @Field_Order;
        }

        # For each form field, if it has a value or the print blank          #
        # fields option is turned on print the form field and value.         #
        foreach $field (@Field_Order) {
            if ($Config{'print_blank_fields'} || $Form{$field} ne '') {
                print MAIL "$field: $Form{$field}\n\n";
            }
        }
    }

    print MAIL "-" x 75 . "\n\n";

    # Send any specified Environment Variables to recipient.                 #
    foreach $env_report (@Env_Report) {
        if ($ENV{$env_report}) {
            print MAIL "$env_report: $ENV{$env_report}\n";
        }
    }

    close (MAIL);

}

sub return_html {
    # Local variables used in this subroutine initialized.                   #
    local($key,$sort_order,$sorted_field);

    # Now that we have finished using form values for any e-mail related     #
    # reasons, we will convert all of the form fields and config values      #
    # to remove any cross-site scripting security holes.                     #
    local($field);
    foreach $field (keys %Config) {
        $safeConfig{$field} = &clean_html($Config{$field});
    }

    foreach $field (keys %Form) {
        $Form{$field} = &clean_html($Form{$field});
    }


    # If redirect option is used, print the redirectional location header.   #
    if ($Config{'redirect'}) {
        print "Location: $safeConfig{'redirect'}\n\n";
    }
```

Comment: I cannot find that code in either version of [FormMail](http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/scripts.shtml).

Comment: @Jamie See http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/faq_nms.html#What_is_this_i_nms_i_thing_all_about And take a look at http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::ContactForm

Comment: @Sinan Unur  thanks, i will definately look into that but for now i really just need a quick fix, whenever i add a redirect i get errors, but there must be a way.

Comment: If you're getting server errors, then it would probably be useful to tell us what those errors are.

Comment: Jamie: matts version has serious security problems.

Comment: Jamie: don't use "local", use "my". Such usage of "local" is a feature of Perl 4, not Perl 5.

Comment: I second the opinion of others here: Please, please, please stop using this code. It's really old, crusty, not that good to begin with, a security problem, perpetuates bad Perl stereotypes and kills kittens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below worked at line 805:

```
    print "Location: " . &clean_html($Config{'missing_fields_redirect'}) . "\n\n";
&send_mail;
```

and then add this in the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="missing_fields_redirect" value="http://www.example.com">
```

but like the comments say, it would be best to update to TFMail (which i will have to do myself shortly)